# How to auto copy when a region is selected?

Tags: copy-paste, region

Chrome browser has an excellent extension called [autocopy](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/auto-copy/bijpdibkloghppkbmhcklkogpjaenfkg?hl=en), which copies text whenever some text is selected/highlighted.

To copy a region in emacs, I have to select the region and then press `M-w` to copy it. But whenever I select a region, I want the region to be copied automatically. How can I achieve that in emacs?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The selection can be copied automatically if the OS supports *primary selection* by setting the below variable.

```el
(setq x-select-enable-primary t)
```

From `C-h v x-select-enable-primary`, you get,

> Non-nil means cutting and pasting uses the primary selection
>   The existence of a primary selection depends on the underlying GUI you use.
>   E.g. it doesn't exist under MS-Windows.

**To learn even more, visit the relevant info node by doing `C-h i g (emacs) Primary Selection`.**

---

Another variable setting that goes in tandem with the above is to set the `x-select-enable-clipboard` to `t`. Doing that allows you to yank the contents copied from other X11 applications into emacs.

```el
(setq x-select-enable-clipboard t)
```

---

When emacs 25.1 is released (supposedly the next stable version after 24.5), the `x-select-enable-primary` variable name will be deprecated and `select-enable-primary` must be used instead (removal of that `x-` prefix). Similarly `x-select-enable-clipboard` will be deprecated in favor of `select-enable-clipboard`.

Answer (score 9):

If you just need this behavior for mouse selections, you can use the built-in setting `mouse-drag-copy-region`:

```
(setq mouse-drag-copy-region t)
```

> If non-nil, copy to kill-ring upon mouse adjustments of the region.

Comment: Most of the time, I use keyboard to select text. Is there a way to enable it for key board selection too?

Comment: @ChillarAnand I don't think there's a built-in option, no. You'll have to wait for someone more knowledgeable to answer. I'm not sure what the best way is to go about this.

Comment: This also works on non-X11 (e.g. Mac OS X)

Comment: @ChillarAnand: on Mac OSX, this command works for both mouse and keyboards selections. Unbelievable but true